# How to serialize/deserialize Pandas DataFrame to and from ProtoBuf/Gzip in a RESTful Flask App?

Tags: python, json, serialization, gzip, protocol-buffers

I have a `pandas dataframe` to be returned as a `Flask Response` object in a `flask` application. Currently I am converting it to a `JSON Object`,

```
df = df.to_json()
return Response(df, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

The dataframe size is really huge of the magnitude, probably 5000000 X 10.
On the client side when I deserialize it as,

```
df = response.read_json()
```

As my number of `URL request parameters` grow, the `dataframe` grows as well. Deserialization time grows at a `linear factor` as compared to serialization, which I would want to avoid. e.g: `Serialization` takes 15-20 seconds, `deserialization` takes 60-70 seconds.

Is there a way that `protobuf` can help in this case to convert pandas dataframe to a protobuf object. Also is there a way that I can send this `JSON` as `Gunzipped` mimetype through flask? I believe there's a comparable timing and efficiency between `protobuf` and `gunzip`.

What's the best solution in such a scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem recently. I solved it by iterating through the rows of my DataFrame and calling protobuf_obj.add() in that loop, using info from the DataFrame. You can then GZIP the serialized string output.

i.e. something along the lines of:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    protobuf_obj.add(val1=row[col1], val2=row[col2])
proto_str = protobuf_obj.SerializeToString()
return gzip.compress(proto_str)
```

Given that this question hasn't been answered in 9 months, I'm not sure there's a better solution but definitely open to hearing one if there is!